# How do I stop Ubuntu from trying to update when a normal user logs in

Tags: updates, users, 19.04

I have an admin account and have several non-admin users for family members. They continually get asked for my password because ubuntu has found software updates.

How can I stop Ubuntu from checking for updates when a normal user is logged in?